# Magento 2 : Is there a event which fires before every controller begins execution?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, frontend, magento2.3.4

The best event I could get was the good old `controller_action_predispatch` but it fires after the controller is done execution and before layout generation.

Any other event that works in frontend area that could do this would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

Some context on why I need this, we've got a store where user can't access any page without login. If I implement it on predispatch the code in the controller can still be executed before redirection to login page.

Comment: Have you tried -    controller_front_send_response_before

Comment: I'll give it a go, but as far as I know it runs after the controller execution and before the return data is sent back to client.

Comment: Can you add what you are trying to perform ? so might get ideas or alternatives.

Comment: please check edit

Comment: Have you checked this - https://inchoo.net/magento/restrict-website-access-require-log/ ?

Comment: It's same as predispatch method as I mentioned previously.

Comment: Have you tried with before interceptors ?

Comment: I am trying to see whether the events direction would work first, hence the question.